# Remove exports variable from webpack generated code

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeorm

I am using Webpack to compile a TypeORM entity from TypeScript to JavaScript.
The code that is being generated looks like this:

```js
/******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    "use strict";
var __webpack_exports__ = {};
// This entry need to be wrapped in an IIFE because it uses a non-standard name for the exports (exports).
(() => {
var exports = __webpack_exports__;

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", ({ value: true }));
class User1629307821282 {
    constructor() {
        this.name = "User1629307821282";
    }
    async up(queryRunner) {
        await queryRunner.query(`
            CREATE TABLE \`database\`.\`user\` (
                \`uuid\` char(36) NOT NULL,
                \`first_name\` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                \`last_name\` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                \`is_active\` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
                PRIMARY KEY (\`uuid\`)
             ) ENGINE=InnoDB`);
    }
    async down(queryRunner) {
        await queryRunner.query(`
            DROP TABLE \`database\`.\`user\`
        `);
    }
}
exports.default = User1629307821282;

})();

/******/ })()
;
```

When I run the command to run my migration, `typeorm migration:run`, it doesn't work, nothing happens.
Now when I remove this piece of code at line 6, it does work and my migration is being executed:

```js
var exports = __webpack_exports__;
```

Is there any option that causes that line to not appear in the generated JavaScript file?
Or is there another way to achieve this? (I know I could just use `tsc` but I would like to use Webpack since I use this for everything in my project.)

Thanks!